# Can you pass this test?

Tags: hex, md5

This was a test posted on a website. It is in two parts. Part one has already been done. It involved compiling to text the following code below. This resulted in this text:

> Visit the website offthebat.co.nz for more details.

The website works if you put in http://www.offthebat.co.nz.

The second part of the test is to work your way around the 404 error the site throws up. I have not been able to do that so would be interesting if anyone else can.

Here was the first part of the test:

```
Binary - 01110110 01101001 01110011 01101001 01110100
visit
Hex - 74 68 65 77 65 62 73 69 74 65
thewebsite
md5 - 3262d48df5d75e3452f0f16b313b7808
off
md5 - 8fc42c6ddf9966db3b09e84365034357
the
md5 - 5f3f4681121b460e3304a1887f42f1c3
bat
binary - 00101110 01100011 01101111 00101110 01101110 01111010
.co.nz
hex - 66 6f 72 20 6d 6f 72 65 20 64 65 74 61 69 6c 73
for more details
```

Comment: It attempts to look for `/IWantAJob`, and states to check the TXT record for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the source of that page, it says:

```
<meta name="description" content="Well done on making it this far, dont give up now. Check the TXT record.">
```

If you do an NSLOOKUP for type=txt for offthebat.co.nz you get:

```
offthebat.co.nz text =
        "Email your details to toni@techs.co.nz with [9x34v] in the subject"
```

I suppose if you send an email to that address with that in the subject line you'll get another clue...